# Splitting CamelCase in R

Tags: r, split, camelcasing

Is there a way to split camel case strings in R?

I have attempted:

```
string.to.split = "thisIsSomeCamelCase"
unlist(strsplit(string.to.split, split="[A-Z]") )
# [1] "this" "s"    "ome"  "amel" "ase"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
string.to.split = "thisIsSomeCamelCase"
gsub("([A-Z]){1}", " \\1", string.to.split)
# [1] "this Is Some Camel Case"
# added a counter to prevent situation mentioned in comment
strsplit(gsub("([A-Z]{1})", " \\1", string.to.split), " ")
# [[1]]
# [1] "this"  "Is"    "Some"  "Camel" "Case" 

# another attempt to meet the commenter's concern
# inserts space between lower-single upper sequence
gsub("([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]]){1}", "\\1 \\2", string.to.split)
```

Looking at Ramnath's and mine I can say that my initial impression that this was an underspecified question has been supported.

And give Tommy and Ramanth upvotes for pointing out `[:upper:]`

```
strsplit(gsub("([[:upper:]])", " \\1", string.to.split), " ")
# [[1]]
# [1] "this"  "Is"    "Some"  "Camel" "Case"
```

Comment: So what if the string is something like 'AB DevelopmentsAndy', which I might want to recreate as "AB Developments Andy". That is, I don't want to split consecutive uppercase characters. Just ones where lowercase then upper case are next to each other.

Comment: You should read `?regex` and find the correct pattern for a lowercase character and use the correct symbol for an arbitrary number of them.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one way to do it

```
split_camelcase <- function(...){
  strings <- unlist(list(...))
  strings <- gsub("^[^[:alnum:]]+|[^[:alnum:]]+$", "", strings)
  strings <- gsub("(?!^)(?=[[:upper:]])", " ", strings, perl = TRUE)
  return(strsplit(tolower(strings), " ")[[1]])
}

split_camelcase("thisIsSomeGood")
# [1] "this" "is"   "some" "good"
```

Comment: +1 since this works with international upper case letters (not just A-Z) - for example, `"enÖIHavet"`

Answer (score 7):

Here's an approach using a single regex (a Lookahead and Lookbehind):

```
strsplit(string.to.split, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "this"  "Is"    "Some"  "Camel" "Case"
```

Comment: Nice, and, to be preferred as it does not split between successive uppercase.
Even better: `strsplit(string.to.split, "(?<=[[:lower:]])(?=[[:upper:]])", perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner using the `gsubfn` package's `strapply`.   The regular expression matches the beginning of the string (`^`) followed by one or more lower case letters (`[[:lower:]]+`) or (`|`) an upper case letter (`[[:upper:]]`) followed by zero or more lower case letters (`[[:lower:]]*`) and processes the matched strings with `c` (which concatenates the individual matches into a vector).  As with `strsplit` it returns a list so we take the first component (`[[1]]`) :

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(string.to.split, "^[[:lower:]]+|[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*", c)[[1]]
## [1] "this"  "Is"    "Camel" "Case"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think my other answer is better than the follwing, but if only a oneliner to split is needed...here we go:

```
library(snakecase)
unlist(strsplit(to_parsed_case(string.to.split), "_"))
#> [1] "this"  "Is"    "Some"  "Camel" "Case"
```

Answer (score 0):

The beginnings of an answer is to split all the characters:

```
sp.x <- strsplit(string.to.split, "")
```

Then find which string positions are upper case:

```
ind.x <- lapply(sp.x, function(x) which(!tolower(x) == x))
```

Then use that to split out each run of characters . . .

Answer (score -1):

Here an easy solution via snakecase + some tidyverse helpers:

```
install.packages("snakecase")
library(snakecase)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

string.to.split = "thisIsSomeCamelCase"
to_parsed_case(string.to.split) %>% 
  str_split(pattern = "_") %>% 
  purrr::flatten_chr()
#> [1] "this"  "Is"    "Some"  "Camel" "Case"
```

Githublink to snakecase: https://github.com/Tazinho/snakecase

Comment: I didn't downvote, but would guess they're due to this answer being much more complicated, and requiring obscure packages, relative to other 1- to 2-line answers.

Comment: I still like this answer, since it is very clean and formats the output. So I leave it here and just provided a oneliner above...