# How to put a space in between a list of strings?

Tags: r, regex, string

This is my current dataset:

```
c("Jetstar","Qantas", "QantasLink","RegionalExpress","TigerairAustralia", 
   "VirginAustralia","VirginAustraliaRegionalAirlines","AllAirlines", 
   "Qantas-allQFdesignatedservices","VirginAustralia-allVAdesignatedservices")
```

I want to add a space in between airlines name and separate it with space.

For this i tried this code:

```
airlines$airline <- gsub("([[:lower:]]) ([[:upper:]])", "\\1 \\2", airlines$airline)
```

But I got the text in the same format as before.

My desired output is as below:

[image]

Comment: Leave of the space between `([[:lower:]])` and `([[:upper:]])`. Please do not provide your data using pictures. Use for example `dput` instead.

Comment: @kath, Thank you for the suggestion. But putting space didnot helped.

Comment: I suggest to remove the space between the two.

Comment: @kath, I got the output for 8 names. But the 9th and 10th names in a data set still appears the same.

Comment: If you provide your data in a reproducible format it is easier to help you.

Comment: Please suggest me how to put it in a reproducible format. I'll put it now.

Comment: Please post data, no pictures. Nobody wants to re-type your stuff!

Comment: As already mentioned: Use `dput`. So in your case `dput(airlines$airline)`. Then edit the question and add the output .

Comment: @kath, I reproduced my question as per your direction. Please see it once.

Comment: Please indent all code lines using 4 spaces.  That will cause it to be automatically formatted.

Comment: @ronak shah, Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txt <- c("Jetstar","Qantas", "QantasLink","RegionalExpress","TigerairAustralia", 
"VirginAustralia","VirginAustraliaRegionalAirlines","AllAirlines", 
"Qantas-allQFdesignatedservices","VirginAustralia-allVAdesignatedservices")
```

You need two different sorts of rules: one for the spaces before the case changes and the other for recurring words ("designated", "services") or symbols ("-"). You could start with a pattern that identified a lowercase character followed by an uppercase character (identified with a character class like "[A-Z]") and then insert a space between those two characters in two capture classes (created with flanking parentheses around a section of a pattern). See the `?regex` Details section for a quick description of character classes and capture classes:

```
gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", txt)
```

You then use that result as an argument that adds a space before any of the recurring words in your text that you want also separated:

```
gsub("(-|all|designated|services)", " \\1", # second pattern and sub for "specials"
gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", txt))  #first pattern and sub for case changes

 [1] "Jetstar"                                      
 [2] "Qantas"                                       
 [3] "Qantas Link"                                  
 [4] "Regional Express"                             
 [5] "Tigerair Australia"                           
 [6] "Virgin Australia"                             
 [7] "Virgin Australia Regional Airlines"           
 [8] "All Airlines"                                 
 [9] "Qantas - all QF designated services"          
[10] "Virgin Australia - all VA designated services"
```

I see that someone upvoted my earlier answer to [Splitting CamelCase in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406974/splitting-camelcase-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) which was similar, but this one had a few more wrinkles to iron out.

Answer (score 1):

This could (almost) do the trick

```
gsub("([A-Z])", " \\1", airlines)
```

Borrowed from: [splitting-camelcase-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406974/splitting-camelcase-in-r)

Of course names like Qantas-allQFd… will stil pose a problem because of the two consecutive UpperCase letters ("QF") in the second part of the string.

Comment: I'm guessing you upvoted my answer to the split camelCase Q. Not sure who downvoted this. Wasn't me. I decided to use a "paired lower-upper sequence" for this pattern to solve the adjacent upper problem you cited.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to figure it out and I have come up with something:

```
library(stringr)

data_vec<- c("Jetstar","Qantas", "QantasLink","RegionalExpress","TigerairAustralia", 
  "VirginAustralia","VirginAustraliaRegionalAirlines","AllAirlines", 
  "Qantas-allQFdesignatedservices","VirginAustralia-allVAdesignatedservices")


str_trim(gsub("(?<=[A-Z]{2})([a-z]{1})", " \\1",gsub("([A-Z]{1,2})", " \\1", data_vec)))
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget to set `perl =TRUE` since am using lookbehind.